# Fill Pandas Dataframe with exisiting dataframe but retain shape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a Pandas dataframe using:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(140), columns=np.arange(20))
```

Which gives me an empty dataframe with 140 rows and 20 columns.

I have another dataframe with 120 columns and 20 rows, I call it `df2`. I would like to add these rows to fill `df`, but still retain the shape of 140x20.

When I use:
`newdf = df.append(df2)` I get a dataframe with 280 rows and 20 columns.

Comment: df.loc[:,:] = df2 ?  i don't really understand ...   do you need to sum or copy? or

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.iloc[:len(df2), :] = df2.values
```

will do the job. As the no. of columns are same so we can safely do this. Other values in df will remain `NaN`s. This will update the df2 records at the beginning. If you want at the end, similarly, you can do `df.iloc[-len(df2):, :] = df2.values`